# angular 12 UI for profile image gallery drag and drop

Tags: angular, image, gallery, drag, drop

I want to build a web UI using angular 12 for a profile page in a social site. The requirement is that the user can drag and drop multiple images to this page with drag and drop capability to form a image gallery.

what are the popular code sample to achieve that?

Comment: I haven't found one, but there are certain things like the Material CDK that could get you started with Drag and Drop UI (even though it doesn't handle dropping of files).